# localhost API key receives Curl error when retrieving access token

Tags: support, api-v2, api-v2.1, authentication

I have registered two apps -- one that will redirect to my website and the other that will redirect to a localhost server that I have running so I don't have to test my code on the site. I have recently noticed that I get a Curl warning

> Error 0 note: Curl was unable to retrieve the data from the specified
>   URL.: Line -- 197 Trace -- 1 File -- D:...\stackphp\src\api.php

I decided to see if this happened with my other key and when I put the code up on my site and started using the website redirected API key I had no issues.

I would really like to not have to test my code online, so any help would be great.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. This seems surprisingly not possible.

Comment: Ten years later, I have a similar error in localhost but working when deployed to remote server.